# Android multiple apps listen to same bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

Let's say we have 2 bluetooth devices, 1 is some device that emits data and the other one is an Android device. Now in the android device, there will be more than 1 app that may run at the same time and would like to listen to that bluetooth connection and process the data received. Is this possible? Or any restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about official, non root android firmwares: no you cannot share memory locations assigned to your application variables(in your case a bluetooth socket inputstream) with other applications.

You can however create one bluetooth client connection in one app, receive the data and then share the data with other applications or services using network sockets or named pipes or files...;